# VBA - Method 'List' of objectr '_CommandBarComboBox' failed

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, worksheet, commandbar

I have a sub in VBA that calls another sub to perform some analysis on data if the user pastes it in. The code below errors as:

Run-time error'-2147467259 (80004005)': 
Method 'List' of object'_CommandBarComboBox' failed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim UndoList As String
    UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)  'Errors Here!

    If Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Then
        Dim Annotations() As String
        FindAnnots
    End If

End Sub
```

Any idea as to why the object's list doesn't exist?

Comment: its working at my end

Comment: Thanks Karthick. Like I said below in my answer, the .List property of Controls("&Undo") depends on actions being stored in the Undo list. If you haven't done anything worthy of being stored there, then it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

After using Bryan's answer about it being a *CommandBarComboBox*, I think you can check its enabled status to see if a list exists. Its the only way I've got it to work without using *On Error Resume Next*.

Use the following loop to capture the status of the ComboBox

```
Dim UndoList As String

If Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Enabled = True Then

    UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)

    If Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Then

        'Code to run here after paste action'

    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:** The *.List* isn't there yet because the user hasn't performed any actions that get saved in the Undo queue. The code is trying to access something that hasn't been created yet. I had to create an error handler for it.

**Long Answer:** In my search, I found that the Controls object in VBA doesn't officially have a List property. However, `Controls("&Undo")` Is not a *Controls* object. It's a *CommandBarComboBox*.

So in

```
Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
```

The .List property of Controls("&Undo") doesn't actually show up in the Excel VBA intellisense. It's looking at the Controls object for it's intellisense drop-down. However, if you try

```
? TypeName(Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo"))
```

In the immediate window, you'll see that it's of the type *CommandBarComboBox*, which does have a list property. However, like other ComboBox style controls, no list is created until a list member is added. In this case, when the user performs an action worthy of being stored in the Undo queue.