# Excel apply formula after pasting table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to create an excel template, which automatically applies a formula if a certain column is inserted? The use case would be:

1. User copies a table from a desktop program (CSV or Tab separated)
2. Pastes the table into the excel template
3. Somehow the column's header gets matched (header's name is fixed)
4. Multiply the column values with a fixed value (like `1.25`)

The problem is that the column could be in different indexes and the formula should apply to all the rows, not just fixed ones, but my main problem is how can I get a copy-paste event and find the column.

Edit.: I can only do this with VBA (never used it before)?

Comment: Is your import always the same number of columns?

Comment: Not always, that is why I am trying to find the column by the header's text

Comment: To detect a paste event using VBA, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818152/excel-vba-how-to-detect-if-something-was-pasted-in-a-worksheet

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column header is constant you could insert a table with "dummy" headers and a calculated column using the header name as a reference
[image]

In the example I have put a formula in the Calc column.  I've put the Calc in column G assuming your maximum import columns are six and because it's good practice to do your calculations from left to right.

You could move the Calc to column A and reduce the "dummy" columns to just 1 with whatever your desired heading is.

To make a template, delete row 3 and clear out the dummy data, just leaving the calculation(s) and save as a `.xltx` in your profile template folder (wherever that may be in your versions of Windows/Office).

When you paste in your import data the table will extend down and copy the formula(s) automatically.  If you have moved your calculation(s) to the left of the table, the table will resize to the right to accommodate all your imported columns.

While the MyHeader column in your template may be over-written, if it can still be found in `Table2[#Headers] the formula will still work.

Comment: Just to be sure: Is this calculates the result to an extra column if it finds the header in my pastes? I really like this approach, but I need to execute the changes on the column that I pasted (I have to apply this to other columns as well, so duplicating every column is not very good).

Comment: If your import has headers and they are consistently named, copy and paste them in.  The `MATCH` part of the formula will find them as long as they are spelt correctly.