# Detect paste event for image

Tags: excel, vba

How can I capture an Event based on "an Image has been pasted to the current worksheet in whatever Target cell"?

- I know how to detect a "Paste" action in a worksheet, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818152/excel-vba-how-to-detect-if-something-was-pasted-in-a-worksheet) here. However, this is based on `Worksheet_Change` which doesn't trigger when pasting an Image.
- I also had a look at catching all paste events as explained [in this article](https://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/catchpaste.asp), but that simply checks for all options (keyboard, mouse, command bar). I would still have to manually do a check for "was it an image that was pasted".

What I am trying to figure out, is basically what happens in that first link (hook into `Worksheet_Change` event and proceed when the `Change` was based on a `Paste`), but can also detect the fact that a `Shape` object has been added to the worksheet, where `Shape.Type` is 13 (as per [these enumerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype))

Any help is much appreciated.

Sample code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'Doesn't trigger on Image Paste
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim imageCnt As Integer
Dim sh As Shape
Dim UndoList As String

Set ws = ActiveSheet
UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
imageCnt = 0

If Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Then 'When paste.
    If Target.Address = "$C$8" Then 'Where user is instructed to paste.
        With ws 'Check if there's a new image:
            For Each sh In .Shapes
                If sh.Type = msoPicture Then
                    imageCnt = imageCnt + 1
                End If
            Next sh
            If imageCnt > oldImageCnt Then 'oldImageCnt publicly declared elsewhere
                Set sh = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
                'Do stuff with the pasted image here.
            End If
        End With
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I can't just event sink the `Shapes` collection or something similar. Any advise/help is much appreciated.

Comment: The only way that I see this working is to run a `Do:DoEvents:Loop` and keep checking the picture count.

Comment: Hm, that would be a possible work around. I'd still prefer capturing "all pastes" and then checking whether I have increased picture count to minimize background code.