# Excel React Add-in: How to access undo stack?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am trying to identify if a cell's data was copy or pasted in an excel sheet within a React Excel Add-in. To do this I found that this can be done in VBA using undo stack: [Excel VBA How to detect if something was pasted in a Worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818152/excel-vba-how-to-detect-if-something-was-pasted-in-a-worksheet)

However, same interfaces are not present in React. Is there any way to access the undo stack in Excel's React add-in?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel web add-ins you can use the `onChanged` event of a worksheet. Event handlers for the `onChanged` event receive a `WorksheetChangedEventArgs` object when the event fires.

The `WorksheetChangedEventArgs` object provides information about the changes and the source. Since `onChanged` fires when either the format or value of the data changes, it can be useful to have your add-in check if the values have actually changed. The details property encapsulates this information as a `ChangedEventDetail`.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .