# Restrict user to paste values in specific columns only manual entry can do

Tags: excel, vba, office365, office-scripts

I am using office 365 and have a file which is updated by 5-10 users. That file contains date validation in around 20 columns.

Now, the issue is that every time somebody enters a non-date value there, by copy-pasting, those validation cells get overwritten.
So, I want to implement some sort of validation with a VBA macro so that users will not be able to paste into those specific columns and will have to manually type in the cells, one by one. I found the below code. but it's not allowing the manual entry as well. Can anybody suggest to me what is the issue in the below given code?

Also, I need your suggestion: if we can use the office script as well, along with VBA, so that if any user opens the file in Excel, online, will that office script take care of this? And if any user opens it in Excel app, will this macro code work?

Please suggest.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim restrictedColumns As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Define the columns where you want to prevent pasting
    Set restrictedColumns = Me.Range("X:X,AB:AB") ' Adjust as needed
    
    ' Check if the changed cell is within the restricted columns
    If Not Intersect(Target, restrictedColumns) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' Disable events
        
        ' Loop through the changed cells
        For Each rng In Target
            If Not Application.Intersect(rng, restrictedColumns) Is Nothing Then
                If rng.Cells.Count = 1 Then ' Check if only a single cell is modified
                    If Not IsEmpty(rng.Value) Then ' Check if the cell is not empty after change
                        ' Clear the pasted data
                        Application.Undo
                        
                        ' Show a message box
                        MsgBox "Pasting is not allowed in this column. Please enter data manually.", vbExclamation, "Data Entry Error"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next rng
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' Re-enable events
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim restrictedColumns As Range
    
    ' Define the columns where you want to prevent pasting
    Set restrictedColumns = Me.Range("X:X,AB:AB") ' Adjust as needed
    
    ' Check if the selected cell is within the restricted columns
    If Not Intersect(Target, restrictedColumns) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            Target.Validation.Delete ' Delete any existing data validation
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_ChangeValidation(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim restrictedColumns As Range
    
    ' Define the columns where you want to prevent pasting
    Set restrictedColumns = Me.Range("X:X,AB:AB") ' Adjust as needed
    
    ' Check if the changed cell is within the restricted columns
    If Not Intersect(Target, restrictedColumns) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Undo
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried the given code as mentioned above.

Comment: you could have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818152/excel-vba-how-to-detect-if-something-was-pasted-in-a-worksheet

Answer (score 1):

You can use a brutal approach of clearing the clipboard so that there's nothing for them to paste.

```
Function ClearClipboard() As String
  CreateObject("htmlfile").parentWindow.clipboardData.setData "text", ""
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

- VBA doesn't work if the file is opened with Excel online app.
- Office Script doesn't support worksheet object events.
- In VBA, Worksheet object doesn't have validation change event "Worksheet_ChangeValidation".
- The data validation is cleared when selecting cells in columns X and AB per the `SelectionChange` event. More details will help determine if it is working as designed.
- There is a some workaround solution that may be helpful for you. It is not perfect either.

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/disable-cut-or-copy-or-paste-in-excel.84495/

Comment: In that case is there any solution for this ? for now I have added 1 row at top of all columns to count non numeric values. at least to know if any issue in the column.

Comment: Add a reference resource from MrExcel.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` event handler to detect if the selection of forbidden columns is being made while a "Copy" command is active and deactivate it

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case True
        Case Intersect(Target, Range("X:X,AB:AB")) Is Nothing ' change the rage address as per your needs
        Case Application.CutCopyMode
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End Select
End Sub
```