# How to disable copy/paste for Excel with VBA to avoid unexpected formatting?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to disable pasting values to make users fill in rows in Excel by applying this script:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
 
Dim UndoString As String

If Range("swAdminMode").Value = "True" Then
    GoTo HandleExit
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
On Error Resume Next  ' required to deal with Undo list being empty
    
UndoString = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Sheet(1)

Err = 0

If Left(UndoString, 5) <> "Paste" Then
   GoTo HandleExit
End If
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
    
Application.Undo
           
On Error Resume Next '- needed to avoid erroring out if data copied from different 
"instance" of excel
        
Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, 
Transpose:=False
        
Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
If Err <> 0 Then 
End If

Err = 0

HandleExit:
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.EnableEvents = True
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

With this, paste is disabled when pasting values for the second time. The first time pasting values still works.

How do I block paste for the Excel spreadsheet completely?

Comment: You could try this: https://jkp-ads.com/articles/catchpaste.asp

Comment: You can also catch the paste event and make sure it pastes the values instead of with formatting. https://superuser.com/questions/1472863/disable-ctrl-v-in-microsoft-excel-allow-paste-with-right-click/1472876#1472876

Answer (score 1):

I was confused by the `UndoString` in your code, until I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818152/excel-vba-how-to-detect-if-something-was-pasted-in-a-worksheet) which I've borrowed from as well.  All we need to do is modify it a bit, and you should have what you need.

Will this work for you?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        
    ' Get the undo list
    Dim UndoList As String

    '~~> Get the undo List to capture the last action performed by user
    UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
    
    '~~> Check if the last action was not a paste nor an autofill
    If Not Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Then GoTo HandleExit
        
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Undo
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    
HandleExit:
    
         
End Sub
```

A few other notes:

- Please only include code relevant to your problem in the future.  For example, the `Range("swAdminMode").Value` check at the beginning is not only irrelevant, but it's also not a check that any user besides you will be able to run, so best not to include it in your posted code.
- When debugging, remove all the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` lines.  Put these back in at the end when the code's working as expected.
- Catch-all error ignoring in `On Error Resume Next` should be avoided whenever possible.  If there's a specific error you're expecting, check for that error alone.